# is calling frame.repaint() at the end of the paint() method dangerous?

Tags: java, swing

Since repaint() calls paint(), isn't calling repaint() at the end of the paint() method using recursion endlessly? If so, why am I not getting a stack overflow error?

Comment: It's not actually a recursive call. Calling `repaint()` just enqueues an event that does the painting later. It's similar to calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not dangerous, since it will just queue in a new paint request. 
It's actually well known practice when developing small games with swing :) 
At least it was at my university!

Comment: Be careful what you learn at university, their theory is a lot better than their practice.